# php laravel preventing multiple logins of a user from different devices/browser tabs at a given time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication

Does laravel provide a way to prevent multiple logins of a user from different devices / browsers at a given time? If yes then how can i force a user to logged in from a single device at a single time. I am developing a online quiz app using laravel 5.6 where users can logged in from a single place and take test.

Comment: There is no such type of functionality but you can do that type of work using database.

Answer (score 3):

laravel provide this method to invalidating and "logging out" a user's sessions that are active on other devices  `logoutOtherDevices()`
to work with this method you need also to  make sure that the

```
Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession
```

middleware is present and un-commented in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class' web middleware group:

```
'web' => [
    // ...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    // ...
],
```

then you can use it like this

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
 Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
```

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps this should get you started:

Add a column in **users_table.php**

```
$table->boolean('is_logged_in')->default(false);
```

When a user logs in: **LoginController.php**

```
public function postLogin()
{
   // your validation

   // authentication check

   // if authenticated, update the is_logged_in attribute to true in users table
   auth()->user()->update(['is_logged_in' => true]);

   // redirect...
}
```

Now, whenever a user tries to login from another browser or device, it should check if that user is already logged in. So, again in **LoginController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->is_logged_in == true) {
        // your error logic or redirect
    }

    return view('path.to.login');
}
```

When a user logs out: **LogoutController.php**

```
public function logout()
{
    auth()->user()->update(['is_logged_in' => false]);

    auth()->logout();

    // redirect to login page...
}
```